# Listeners and Observables JavaFX implementation

Tags: javafx, observable, listener, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a text-based adventure game where players enter commands and move through the map of rooms. I have an issue where the current room the player is in remains the same no matter what command is entered. My walk [Direction] command works, but it does not update the model of the game of the new room it moved to, it remains the current room..

I have researched Listeners and Observables but I am not exactly sure how to implement it in my game.. I used JavaFXML.

This is part of the method that interprets the input the player enters into a textfield on the GUI, it is in the Controller class that controls the interface:

```
    void InterpretInput(KeyEvent e) throws NullPointerException {
    if (e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
        //setUpGame();
        Output.clear();
        String input = Input.getText();
        Command c = CommandParser.parse(input);
        //c.getCommandType();//is this reference to the first word >yes


        //assert c != null;
        //String arg = null;
        if (c != null) {
            String arg = c.getArg();
            //}
            // reference to second word?

            //ct = CommandType.fromString(ct.toString());

            try {
                switch (c.getCommandType()) {
                    case WALK:
                        Room newRoom = curGame.WalkCommand(input, curPlayer);
                        if (newRoom == null) {
                            Output.appendText("There is no room in that direction!");
                        } else {
                            Output.appendText("You have now moved to " + newRoom.getName());
                            curPlayer.setCurrentRoom(newRoom);

                        }


                        Input.clear();
                        break;

                    case LOOK:
                        curRoom = curGame.LookCommand(input, curPlayer);
                        if (curRoom.getLightsOn())
                            Output.appendText("You are currently in room: " + curRoom.getName() + "Room Description : " + curRoom.getDescription());

                        else {
                            Output.appendText("The room is completely dark! Try finding a torch to light up the room to see your surroundings!");

                        }
                        Input.clear();
                        break;
```

Also in the controller class, the game is setup:

```
Game curGame = new Game();
Room curRoom = curGame.getGizaRoom();
Player curPlayer = new Player(curRoom);
```

In the Game class, which sets up the game and has the actions of the commands the walk command look like this: (part of it)

```
public Room WalkCommand(String arg, Player curGame){

      Room curRoom = curGame.getCurrentRoom();
      Command c = CommandParser.parse(arg);
      Direction d = Direction.fromString(c.getArg());
      //Direction c = Direction.fromString();
      ;
      Room newRoom;
      switch (d) {
          case EAST:
              newRoom = goEast(curRoom);
              curGame.setCurrentRoom(newRoom);
              return newRoom;


public Room goEast(Room curRoom) {
  Room newRoom;
  newRoom = curRoom.getRoom(EAST);
  if (newRoom != null) {
      return newRoom;
  }
  else
      return null;
}
```

How would I use listeners or observable list to ensure the current room the player is in gets updated while playing the game?

Comment: [mcve] please - and stick to java naming conventions

Comment: Read up on [JavaFX properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) (documentation is old, but still relevant).